# Difference between TPU and VPU

Tags: hardware

There are these two concepts of ASICs for the usage for neural networks.
The one is called Tensor Processing Unit [(TPU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_Processing_Unit) and the other one is called a Vision Processing Unit [(VPU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_processing_unit). How do they differ from each other? I don't want to dig to deep into differences in terms of architecture but more or less application wise. Is it at the end of the day just naming convention, but they can be used for the same stuff?